# Embedding website in iframe not working

Tags: iframe

I am trying to embed the website www.zillow.com in iframe

```
<iframe src="http://www.zillow.com" style="width:33%;height:440px;" scrolling="yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"><p><b>Zillow</b></p></iframe>
```

But it does not return anything just blank, please advise

Comment: You need a the parent Element to have a width to use `%`. What is the width? Also, many of those `iframe` attributes are not available in HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on the subject but my guess if they are blocking iframe access via .htaccess and/or javascript

See these previous posts for additional information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273665/getting-past-facebooks-iframe-block#answers-header) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881139/how-to-block-iframe-call)

Comment: +1 yes and I don't know if you can achieve that or not but when I tried other sites it shows them without any problem so it should be a thing that relates to that site.

Comment: If you would like another example of a website blocking an iframe try Facebook.  You'll get the same blank result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i was able to embed other sites such as redfin and mris in iframe but not zillow..
They do block the iframe access.
Anyway thanks for the guidance